# error: '.class' expected in the following Java code

Tags: java

Here in the following code I am trying to print the difference of two arrays but I am getting this class error: '.class' expected

Its coming on here

```
  ArrayCopy9526.java:15: error: '.class' expected
       int[] buffer = new int[array1];
```

And below is my full code.

```
public class ArrayCopy9526 {
   public static void main(String[] args){
      int[] sourceArr = {0,1,23,4,45,5,667,7,764,8,23};
      int[] arrayAno = {2,3,34,45,456,56,13,123,8,23};


      arrayDiff(sourceArr, arrayAno);

   }
  public static void arrayDiff(int[] arrayOne, int[] arrayTwo){
     int array1 = arrayOne.length;
     int array2 = arrayTwo.length;

      if(array1 < array2)   
       int[] buffer = new int[array1];
     else
       int[] buffer = new int[array2];

       for(int i = 0; i < array1; i++ ){
         for(int j= 0; j < array2; j++) {
           if(arrayOne[i] != arrayTwo[j]){
            buffer[i] = arrayOne[i];
           }
         }             
       }

    for(int i :buffer){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
  } 
}
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Does it say on what line it's expecting the `.class`?

Comment: provide us with diagnostics

Comment: I have upated the question @AntonH. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buffer` goes out of scope at the end of the `if` statement.

Declare `buffer` before the `if` or use a ternary operator:

```
int[] buffer = new int[array1 < array2 ? array1 : array2];
```

Comment: Nice way to do initialisation. Thanks

Comment: It does allow initialisation but the scoping rules of if statements override that. This all leads to better program stability.

Comment: So because a block specifies the scope in Java the buffer is going out of scope after the if block and is not available for the rest of code.

Answer (score 5):

For the bodies of your `if` and `else`, you must have a statement or a block, not a declaration.  The ".class expected" message is confusing, but it comes on the declaration.  "Not a statement" might have been a clearer message.

Declare your `buffer` before your `if` and assign it in your `if` and `else`.

```
int[] buffer;
if(array1 < array2)
   buffer = new int[array1];
else
   buffer = new int[array2];
```

Comment: Thanks Dude its first time I cam across this.

Comment: Why Declaration is not considered a statement?

Comment: As the body of an `if` or `else`, it's useless.  It goes out of scope immediately.